# how to give input as java project and get code as diagram using PlantUML

Tags: plantuml

I am trying to use PlantUML (http://plantuml.com/). I want to have my Java project (call stacks) converted as diagram in PlantUML. I see it can generate technical diagrams by writing lines of code/text. I know about text. But, how to give input as java project and get code as diagram? please suggest if you anyone know about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Some IDEs have plug-ins/extensions to do this. You can try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15991-plantuml-diagram-generator. There is also sketchit, but I think it's not maintained lately.